# amdgpu not loading properly

Tags: amdgpu

I have a problem with booting into Ubuntu. I have reinstalled the system since I thought that the cause is somewhere else but the problem still appears - the boot stops while printing the following:

```
/dev/nvme...: clean etc...
```

The problem only appears when booting after turning off the computer and waiting for a while. If I somehow manage to boot properly (hard resets and it sometimes works), then rebooting goes normally. I can't enter TTY while the boot hangs.
Setting nomodeset in grub allows me to boot properly.

Ubuntu 22.04.3

kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic

GPU: AMD Radeon RX5500XT

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

I checked journalctl and see the following red marked lines:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: SMU: I'm not done with your previous command: SMN_C2PMSG_66:0x00000006 SMN_C2PMSG_82:0x00000000
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to enable requested dpm features!
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to setup smc hw!
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <smu> failed -62
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: amdgpu 0000:2b:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
```

While using kernel 6.2.0-37-generic, the first two lines from above listing does not appear in the journalctl.

And the following regarding GPU

```
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 367 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_irq.c:600 amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: Modules linked in: ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc amdgpu(+) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlmvm intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec mac80211 iommu_v2 snd_hda_core kvm_amd drm_buddy snd_hwdep gpu_sched drm_ttm_helper snd_pcm libarc4 ttm kvm drm_display_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event btusb cec irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul snd_rawmidi rc_core polyval_clmulni btrtl polyval_generic iwlwifi snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel btbcm sha512_ssse3 btintel aesni_intel drm_kms_helper btmtk snd_seq_device i2c_algo_bit nls_iso8859_1 snd_timer crypto_simd bluetooth syscopyarea sysfillrect cryptd snd joydev sysimgblt ecdh_generic input_leds rapl cfg80211 video wmi_bmof ccp soundcore ecc k10temp mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  crc32_pclmul nvme r8169 i2c_piix4 nvme_core ahci xhci_pci realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common wmi gpio_amdpt
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 367 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd MS-7B86/B450-A PRO MAX (MS-7B86), BIOS M.E0 01/18/2022
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: Code: 31 f6 31 ff e9 dd 77 8e d9 44 89 ea 4c 89 e6 4c 89 f7 e8 8f fc ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d 31 d2 31 f6 31 ff e9 bc 77 8e d9 <0f> 0b b8 ea ff ff ff eb c3 b8 ea ff ff ff eb bc b8 fe ff ff ff eb
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb8318189b8d8 EFLAGS: 00010246
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RBP: ffffb8318189b8f8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9c634766bea8
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9c6347660000 R15: 0000000000000001
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: FS:  00007f924b6488c0(0000) GS:ffff9c666ea80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: CR2: 00007f07710de920 CR3: 0000000117f5a000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: Call Trace:
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  <TASK>
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? show_regs+0x72/0x90
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? __warn+0x8d/0x160
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? report_bug+0x1bb/0x1d0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x19/0x80
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? amdgpu_irq_put+0x59/0xc0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_fence_driver_hw_fini+0x10b/0x150 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_device_fini_hw+0xbc/0x240 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_driver_unload_kms+0x4d/0x70 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_driver_load_kms+0xf9/0x1c0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_pci_probe+0x169/0x470 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  local_pci_probe+0x4b/0xb0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  pci_call_probe+0x55/0x190
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  pci_device_probe+0x84/0x120
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  really_probe+0x1ed/0x450
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  __driver_probe_device+0x8a/0x190
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  driver_probe_device+0x23/0xd0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  __driver_attach+0x10f/0x220
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? __pfx___driver_attach+0x10/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  bus_for_each_dev+0x83/0xe0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  driver_attach+0x1e/0x30
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  bus_add_driver+0x152/0x250
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  driver_register+0x83/0x160
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? __pfx_init_module+0x10/0x10 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  __pci_register_driver+0x68/0x80
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  amdgpu_init+0x69/0xff0 [amdgpu]
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  do_one_initcall+0x49/0x240
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? kmalloc_trace+0x2a/0xb0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  do_init_module+0x52/0x240
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  load_module+0xb96/0xd60
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? security_kernel_post_read_file+0x5c/0x80
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? kernel_read_file+0x25c/0x2b0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  __do_sys_finit_module+0xcc/0x150
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xcc/0x150
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x18/0x30
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5c/0x90
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? switch_fpu_return+0x55/0xf0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xaf/0xd0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x38/0x60
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  ? sysvec_call_function+0x4e/0xb0
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x73/0xdd
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f924b51ea7d
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: Code: 5b 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 83 a3 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fff2bc643e8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055ae546890d0 RCX: 00007f924b51ea7d
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f924b7d6441 RDI: 000000000000001c
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000002
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: R10: 000000000000001c R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f924b7d6441
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: R13: 000055ae54686c30 R14: 000055ae546891c0 R15: 000055ae5468a930
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel:  </TASK>
lis 21 16:51:14 bartek-pc kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

I had similar problems when I bought the PC and it stopped with some update.

I also tried this [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/2033569) but it did not help.

I do not know whether it would mean something but before the fresh installation of Ubuntu the problem appeared after I installed powertop, nvtop (my bad) and radeontop. I probably also updated the system so it could be no connection.

Could someone please help me with resolving the issue?

**EDIT**
I tried Fedora and got nothing. Reinstalled Xubuntu opted in the third party packages and installed amdgpu drivers using [amdgpu-install](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the graphics usecase. The system boots now every time, without hanging at boot but after invoking lshw, it states that the graphics card is UNCLAIMED. journalctl shows the same amdgpu errors as in the snippet above.